# Why does size not override.aes in guides()?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, legend

I have this volcano plot

[image]

I want to remove the `logp`-line in the legend. I, therefore, tried

```
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)),
         size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10))) +
```

and `... size = guide_legend(override.aes = NA))` and `... size = guide_legend(override.aes = "none"))`

However, this did not solve it. How can I remove that specific part?

My script

```
ggplot(BT_Ctrl, aes(x = diff, y = logp)) + 
  geom_point(data = filter(BT_Ctrl, 
                           (logp > 0 & logp < (-log(0.1))) | (logp > (-log(0.1)) & diff > (-1) & diff < 0) 
  ),
  alpha = 0.35, size = 3, color = "grey50", fill = "grey60", shape=21, stroke = 1) +

  geom_point(data = filter(BT_Ctrl,
                           (logp > (-log(0.1)) & diff < (-1)) | (logp > (-log(0.1)) & diff > 0)) %>%
               mutate(group = ifelse(diff > 0, "Tumor", "Ctrl")),
             aes(color = group, fill = group, size = logp), shape = 21, stroke = 1) +
  
  scale_size(range = c(4,8)) +
  
  scale_fill_manual(values = alpha(c("#D1B551", "#678F53"), 0.2),
                    name = "",
                    labels = c("Low abundant", 
                               "High abundant")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("#D1B551", "#678F53"),
                      name = "",
                      labels = c("Low abundant", 
                                 "High abundant")) +
  
  scale_alpha_manual(values=c(0.01, 0.2, .1), guide = "none") +
  
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-3, 4, 1),
                     name = "**Difference on log<sub>2</sub>-scale**") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 8, 1),
                     name = "**-log**(*P*-value)") +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 8),
                  xlim = c(-3.5, 4)) +
  
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)),
         size = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10))) +
  
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", 
                                 size = .6),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(colour = "gray95"),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour = "gray95"),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 16), 
        axis.title.x = ggtext::element_markdown(color = "grey20", size = 22, 
                                                margin = ggplot2::margin(t = 10)),
        axis.text.y = element_text(color = "grey20", size = 16), 
        axis.title.y = ggtext::element_markdown(color = "grey20", size = 25, 
                                                margin = ggplot2::margin(r = 8)),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        plot.title = ggtext::element_markdown(color = "grey20", 
                                              size = 20, hjust = 0),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        legend.text = ggtext::element_markdown(size = 30), 
        legend.title = element_text(size = 20, hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

With data sample:

```
 BT_Ctrl <- structure(list(logp = c(1.892315213, 1.741122091, 0.561899231, 
0.036655082, 0.980036153, 0.17522181, 0.091824698, 0.108312434, 
1.271318168, 1.076396099, 0.810250042, 0.260831199, 0.215034285, 
0.757343375, 0.482811756, 0.744494045, 0.289560753, 0.88281578, 
0.413021101, 0.277454405, 2.05682268, 0.004352447, 0.830231027, 
0.733181724, 0.355808451, 0.494777499, 0.272399182, 0.734279471, 
0.904390655, 0.093881396, 2.263531464, 2.183779415, 0.002000274, 
0.288928922, 0.108312434, 1.631564514, 1.863799992, 0.038540997, 
0.351032435, 0.389484032, 0.27672349, 0.868411145, 0.146638783, 
0.222894374, 0.785553332, 0.503424902, 0.007184975, 0.143643702, 
0.706542278, 0.399474359, 1.398223879, 0.277454405, 0.070263867, 
0.196525572, 0.714977904, 0.359791631, 1.53290454, 1.319926396, 
2.539142436, 1.481669911, 0.227928051, 0.105656067, 0.571121048, 
0.098156733, 0.063262205, 0.73837595, 0.064271242, 0.601613347, 
0.122076363, 1.691585028, 0.537070368, 0.001707348, 0.937587345, 
1.902615044, 0.26791295, 0.939251545, 0.027628346, 0.333192597, 
2.454661239, 0.430268931, 0.517377715, 1.795537119, 0.899703873, 
0.171224188, 0.407711105, 0.101449286, 1.989191981, 0.250549532, 
0.276978823, 3.759602247, 0.253764539, 0.031279861, 0.130796447, 
0.269354234, 0.598702594, 2.600656132, 0.105037153, 1.125756856, 
0.265984845, 0.053120566), diff = c(1.20234619, -1.70295885, 
0.65457164, 0.06714772, -0.80261127, -0.26141931, 0.13191337, 
-0.17023798, -1.00645538, -1.12120783, 0.78954709, 0.39286592, 
0.3128407, 0.94129525, -0.65648018, -0.55756632, -0.30731923, 
-0.89000336, 0.59985586, 0.43502626, -1.55898508, -0.00761563, 
-0.70479107, 0.71041436, -0.50044067, -0.62982497, -0.44573634, 
-0.75347176, -0.8137711, -0.16123801, 1.77236427, -1.87675892, 
-0.00340981, -0.29575161, -0.17023798, 1.307873, -1.72798215, 
0.06637002, -0.46851144, -0.55572908, -0.37359508, 0.72585016, 
-0.17725634, 0.34547909, 0.61925212, -0.53240673, 0.01361836, 
-0.23351898, 0.93210313, -0.34450825, 1.09251706, 0.43502626, 
-0.09880463, -0.25131522, -0.73972942, -0.48159189, -1.46794924, 
1.07828034, -1.6589846, -0.99656108, -0.31415414, -0.13807622, 
0.51838817, 0.19589304, -0.0937803, 0.75802953, -0.09147411, 
0.67878846, 0.19139068, 1.52384739, 0.51390223, -0.00206126, 
-1.04672091, 1.55164341, -0.4140512, 0.83026286, 0.04245698, 
-0.41767947, 1.78143388, -0.48238462, -0.48817196, -1.57535168, 
-0.99213411, -0.23038557, -0.46668723, -0.17994928, -1.36902852, 
0.32038784, 0.34062497, 1.93588366, 0.26186093, 0.04413918, -0.20751399, 
-0.33032721, -0.52244521, 1.59749734, 0.14740854, -0.85269934, 
0.33985544, 0.0960661)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply

`guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 10)), size = "none")`

did it